# Profile Picture from URL not showing in 2010

Tags: 2010, active-directory, user-profile-service, picture, active-directory-import

I am trying to import profile pictures using PictureURL. We have a full url stored in extensionAttribute3(`http://pictureserver/photo/GetPhoto.aspx?id=xyz`)(could it be because my url isn't linking straight to a .jpg?) . I have followed directions below to map extensionAttribute3 to PictureURL

http://www.chaitumadala.com/2010/05/setting-up-pictureurl-user-profile.html

As far as I can tell, the mapping is complete and UPS job is running fine. However, a picture never shows.

Any suggestions?

Comment: cross check with this blog...http://spmat.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-map-sharepoint-2010-pictureurl.html

Comment: All of that checks out. The only thing I can guess is Sharepoint doesn't recognize it as a picture since it's not straight to the .jpg

Comment: did you try to straight point it to jpg?

Comment: Haven't been able to try pointing to a .jpg. Just realized our pictures are actually stored in a table on sql server. The url is doing a lookup based on that. Does anyone have any experience in retrieving profile pics from this type of data source?